# Inserting text at the beginning of all lines selected in visual line mode

Tags: visual-block, custom-text-object

I have selected a JS block such as following:

```
function map(xs: string[], cb: Function) : string[] {
  const result: string[] = [];
  for(let i = 0; i++; i < xs.length) {
    result.push(cb(xs[i]));
  }

  return result;
}
```

Now I want to go to the beginning of each line and comment out each line in the block (inserting `//` at the beginning of each line). How can I do this in the fastest way possible using text objects? I am aware that this is also possible by doing column selection <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>V</kbd>, `<number>`<kbd>j</kbd>, <kbd>I</kbd>, `//` and <kbd>ESC</kbd> sequence. But I want to do this in the fastest way possible.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can try this:

```
vip<Ctrl-v>I//<ESC>
```

1. `vip` select paragraph
2. `<Ctrl-v>` make selection blockwise
3. `I//` insert `//` into begining of a selection block

[image]

PS: I would suggest to use vim-commentary plugin from Tim Pope where it would be simple `gcip`.

Answer (score 0):

I think the fastest would be using the commentary plugin as Maxim Kim mentioned: just type `gc` since you already have the lines selected. But if you want another option using vanilla vim, you could try using regex substitution:

```
:s&^&//
```

You can use other characters instead of `&`; I used that one because it's next to `^` on my keyboard. I use it instead of the standard `/` to avoid having to escape the slashes in the substitution, as in:

```
:s/^/\/\/
```

but that also works.